# Is there a way to get value from adjacent column of data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list consisting of symbols like ['T.TO', 'VCB.TO']

I have a dataframe like this:

```
  1 RIC     Expected Return
  2 T.TO    2
  3 A.TO    1.1
  4 VCB.TO  0.004
  5 ASN.TO  3
  6 00G.H   1.1
```

and so one with different RICS. Not all values in RIC column is in symbols.

What I want to do is iterate over symbols and extract corresponding return from the dataframe.

Something like this:

```
for i in symbols:
     if i in df.RIC:
         list_returns.append(df.Expected Return.index(i))
```

I know this is really not the correct syntax to deal with dataframes. I could convert it to a dictionary and then handle it using for loops but is there a way to handle it directly using dataframes?

Expected Output: list_returns = [2, 1.1]

The actual dataframe and symbols list are much larger in size.

Comment: You want to add returns of your dataframe to the corresponding RIC in your list, did I understand you correct?

Comment: one sure thing: `df.Expected Return.index(i)` does not run

Comment: Yes that's right!

Comment: A sample of your RICS dataframe, and a sample of your expected output would help

Comment: `df.loc[df.RIC.isin(symbols), 'Expected Return'].value`?

Comment: Convert your symbols list to a dataframe: `symb = pd.DataFrame({'RIC':symbols})` Then do a simple merge: `symb.merge(df, on='RIC')`

Comment: @G.Anderson I have updated my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `isin`, `loc`, and `tolist` would give you the list:

```
df.loc[df.RIC.isin(symbols), 'Expected_Return'].tolist()

Out[933]: [2.0, 0.004]
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert your symbols list to a dataframe, the simply [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
symb = pd.DataFrame({'RIC':symbols})

symb.merge(df, on='RIC')
```

---

```
      RIC  Expected Return
0    T.TO            2.000
1  VCB.TO            0.004
```

For more info about merging, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)